# Writing a program to calculate Happy Numbers in Pascal. Stuck with an infinite loop

Tags: freepascal

I'm writing a procedure to do the calculating. The program asks the user for any number between 1 and 9999 and then calculates whether or not that number is a happy number.

```
program EindEvaluatieProceduresFuncties2;

   uses wincrt, math;

   var lucky: boolean;
    num: longint;
    i, j: integer;
    arr: array [1..4] of integer;
    sum: integer;


   procedure HappyNumber;

   begin
   repeat
   begin
        repeat
        begin
            i:=i+1;
            //writeln('i = ',i);
            arr[i]:=num mod 10;
            //writeln( 'a[i] = ', arr[i] );
            num:=num div 10;
            //writeln ( 'n = ', num );
       end;
       until num=0;
       //writeln('Digits are : ');
       //for j:=i downto 1 do
       //writeln('a[j] = ', arr[j],'   ', j);
       //writeln('Calculating Happy Number');
       for j := i downto 1 do
       sum := sum + (Sqr(arr[j]));
       for j := i downto 1 do
       writeln('sum = ',sum);
       num := sum;

   end;
   until sum < 10 ;
   end;

   begin
     lucky := false;
     writeln('Please give a positive number below 10000.');
     readln(num);
     while ( num < 1 ) or ( num > 9999 ) do
     begin
       writeln('Number must be positive and less than 10000. Try again.');
       readln(num);
     end;
     HappyNumber;
     if (lucky = True) then
     begin
       writeln(num, ' is a happy number.');
     end
     else
     begin
       writeln(num, ' is not a happy number.');
     end;
     writeln('');
     writeln('Press < ENTER > to end the program.');
     readln;
   end.
```

Within the procedure I have the command i := 0; as seen below:

```
procedure HappyNumber;

       begin
       repeat
       begin
            repeat
            begin
                i:=0;
                i:=i+1;
```

This is where the problem occurs. If I do this it becomes an infinite loop, however if I place the command outside of the repeat loop then i does not reset to 0 at the beginning of every iteration of the loop, which I need it to.

I should point out that much of the code is there at the moment simply to let me see what is happening and wont be a part of the final code. Wherever I have inserted "//" are those lines.

I am aware that there is perhaps a better way I could be doing this whole program. If anyone has any suggestions for how I can make it easier, I'd also appreciate that very much.

Thank you.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Put the `i:=0;` above the second `repeat` and it will initialize to 0 every outer repeat (which is what you want). B.T.W. your program will still hang on unhappy numbers (as is defined by "unhappy number") so you need to build in some mechanism to detect that you are in a loop. (you can also remove begin/end within the repeat/until. Repeat/until already "act" as a begin/end block)

Comment: An extra note: You do `until sum < 10;` as if numbers below 10 and not 1 are unhappy. That's not true. For example 7 is happy. `7 > 49 > 97 > 130 > 10 > 1`. Number 4 ends in a loop: `4 > 16 > 37 > 58 > 89 > 145 > 42 > 20 > 4 > 16 > 37 > 58 > .....` etc. So you always need to cache the numbers you saw and if you see a repeat you're in a loop (which is unhappy). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard of happy / unhappy numbers and found it quite interesting to solve this task :-)

There is still a lot to optimize but I think you can use it for studying.

```
program EindEvaluatieProceduresFuncties2;

uses SysUtils, crt ;

var input: string;
    number: integer;
    code: integer;

function HapyNumber(num: integer):boolean;
var
  erg: integer;
  digit: integer;
begin
  Result := true;
  erg := 0;
  if num = 4 then Result := false;
  if num = 4 then exit;
  if num = 1 then exit;
  if num = 0 then exit;

  // serialize the number into digits and calculate the next number
  while num > 0 do begin
    digit := num mod 10;
    num   := num div 10;
    erg := erg + digit * digit;
    write(IntToStr(digit) + ' ');
  end;

  write(IntToStr(num) + ' ');
  writeln('=' + IntToStr(erg));
  Result := HapyNumber(erg);
end;

begin

  repeat
    writeln('Please give a positive number below 10000.' + sLineBreak + 'Number must be positive and less than 10000.' + sLineBreak + 'Type x for exit!');
    readln(input);
    if lowerCase(input) = 'x' then exit;
    val(input, number, code);
    if code <> 0 then begin
      ClrScr;
      writeln('Invalid number "' + input + '" !');
    end
      else if (number > 0) and (number <= 9999) then begin
        ClrScr;
        writeln('Cheking ' + IntToStr(number) + '..');
        if HapyNumber(number) then writeln(number, ' is a happy number.')
          else writeln(number, ' is not a happy number.');
        writeln('Press enter to continue');
        readln;
        ClrScr;
      end;

  until lowerCase(input) = 'x';
end.
```

The important codepart is

```
  while num > 0 do begin
    digit := num mod 10;
    num   := num div 10;
    erg := erg + digit * digit;
    write(IntToStr(digit) + ' '); // just output the tmp result
  end;
```

It serialize a number into digits (1973 will be 3 7 9 1)

**I used recursion just for fun and it is not really necessary :-)**

Comment: Omg thank you so much for this and I'm sorry I never replied sooner. I've been swamped and let this assignment sit on the side for a few days.

There is something I would like to ask though. The variable erg. What is that, what does the name stand for?

Comment: I used erg as a help variable. It's value is always printed once per call of the function HapyNumber. Feel free to ask when there is something unclear. Please vote up my answer if it solves your question. :-)